# Replacing select values with values from other tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I am trying to query upon a table, where I want to replace it's foreign key with a value the related table has a fk constraint to. I don't know how to explain it better in words - I have made a minimal example to demonstrate my difficulty.

```sql
    create table customers (
        cpr VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    );

    CREATE TABLE accounts (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        balance INT DEFAULT 0,
        customerCpr VARCHAR(10) references customers (cpr) NOT NULL,
    );

    CREATE TABLE transactions(
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        retriever INT references accounts (id) NOT NULL,
        giver     INT references accounts (id) NOT NULL,
        timestamp timestamp default current_timestamp,
        amount    INT NOT NULL
    );
```

So I want to query something like

```sql
SELECT retrieverCustomer.name, giverCustomer.name, tran.timestamp tran.amount 
FROM transactions tran 
WHERE tran.retriever = 20 OR tran.giver = 20...
```

I want it to return this format:

```
 id | retName   | gName |         timestamp          | amount 
----+-----------+-------+----------------------------+--------
  1 | Elisabeth | Jonas | 2020-05-09 11:07:50.614155 |   1500
  2 |  Veronica | Peter | 2020-05-09 11:07:50.614155 |   2200
  3 |Kristoffer | Jens  | 2020-05-09 11:07:50.614155 |   1700
```

I am not sure how to achieve this, I have tried with some joining and some conditionals but I fail to see the problem through. If someone know how to achieve this or can explain why it is not ideal to do so it would really help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to join the acounts and customers table twices, one time as the giver, one time as the retriever:

```
SELECT cr.name as retriever_customer, cg.name as giver_customer, t.timestamp, t.amount 
FROM transactions t
JOIN accounts ar on ar.id = t.retriever
JOIN accounts ag on ag.id = t.giver
JOIN customers cr on cr.cpr = ar.customercpr
JOIN customers cg on cg.cpr = ag.customercpr
WHERE t.retriever = 20 OR t.giver = 20
ORDER BY t.timestamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a place where a CTE can prove clearer:

```
with ac as (  -- accounts with the customer name added on
      select a.*, c.name
      from accounts a join
           customers c
           on a.customercpr = c.cpr
     )
select t.id, acg.name as giver_name, acr.name as retriever_name, t.timestamp, t.amount
from transactions t join
     ac acg
     on acg.id = t.giver join
     ac acr
     on acr.id = t.retriever 
where 20 in (t.giver, t.retriever);
```